# XBAP - This application type has been disabled

Tags: .net, wpf, internet-explorer-9, xbap

I have an XBAP on my website that used to work.  I checked it today for the first time in ages and found it's not working on Win7 x64 / IE9.

http://drewnoakes.com/code/wpf/flags/demo/demo.xbap

The error message I see is:

> Startup URI: http://drewnoakes.com/code/wpf/flags/demo/demo.xbap
>   Application Identity: http://drewnoakes.com/code/wpf/flags/demo/demo.xbap#demo.xbap, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d8e235cc7c0267c, processorArchitecture=msil/demo.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d8e235cc7c0267c, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
>
> This application type has been disabled.

Can anyone explain what this means or provide information about how I might debug this further?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

- [IE9 - XBAPs Disabled in the Internet Zone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/09/internet-explorer-9-xbap-disabled-in-the-internet-zone.aspx)

Apparently you can undo the change IE9 made to `URLACTION_WINDOWS_BROWSER_APPLICATIONS` or you could change the zone for your site.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I suppose the error message makes sense in hindsight, but it would be nice if it listed these options to the user, as this looks like there's an error on the site.

Answer (score 32):

Or you can enable XBAP applications in IE9.

Security -> .NET Framework -> XAML browser applications

- Disable
- **Enable**
- Prompt

[image]

Comment: I advise against this. There have been vulnerabilities found in the underlying infrastructure: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-004

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add derewnoakes.com to the **Trusted sites**.

[How to add to the trusted sites?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-do-i-add-a-site-to-my-trusted-sites-list/98cc77c8-b364-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)